# AWS C++ SDK, SQS thows access violation

Tags: c++11, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-sqs

Trying to create an SQS queue with AWS C++ SDK.

```
Aws::SDKOptions options; 
Aws::InitAPI(options); 
Aws::Client::ClientConfiguration configuration; 
configuration.region = Aws::Region::US_WEST_2; 
Aws::SQS::SQSClient sqs = new Aws::SQS::SQSClient(Aws::Auth::AWSCredentials("abc", "def"), configuration);
```

Running on Windows, 64 bit, VC++.

When I run I will get an access violation:

```
Exception thrown at 0x000007FEE4E9C83C (aws-cpp-sdk-core.dll) in TestDB.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000000.
```

This will happen deep in the call chain of the sdk. There are no parameters I can pass here as null pointers, so i'm not sure what it can be. I'm able to run against S3 with no issues, just SQS.

It looks like a missing initialization (but Aws::InitAPI(options); is called), or something with the memory management (which i use the default). Latest SDK version.

Any help or ideas will be appreciated.

-Yishai

Changed call to use Aws::SQS::SQSClient*, update all NuGet packages to the latets version (ends with x.60). This is the stack trace:

```
aws-cpp-sdk-core.dll!000007fee4dfd4bc() Unknown
aws-cpp-sdk-core.dll!000007fee4d07962() Unknown
aws-cpp-sdk-core.dll!000007fee4d30a11() Unknown
aws-cpp-sdk-core.dll!000007fee4d301a5() Unknown
aws-cpp-sdk-core.dll!000007fee4d02710() Unknown
aws-cpp-sdk-sqs.dll!000007fee4ffe4e1()  Unknown
aws-cpp-sdk-sqs.dll!000007fee5046872()  Unknown
aws-cpp-sdk-sqs.dll!000007fee5046968()  Unknown
aws-cpp-sdk-sqs.dll!000007fee5046778()  Unknown
aws-cpp-sdk-sqs.dll!000007fee502f125()  Unknown
aws-cpp-sdk-sqs.dll!000007fee5002986()  Unknown
aws-cpp-sdk-sqs.dll!000007fee4fd2198()  Unknown
```

> 

TestDB.exe!AmazonSQSQueue::AmazonSQSQueue(std::basic_string,std::allocator > queueIdentifier, Aws::Auth::AWSCredentials * cred) Line 263  C++

```
TestDB.exe!AmazonQueuesHolder::initilizeSQS(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > accessKey, std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > secretKey, std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > incommingQueueName, std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > highPriorityQueueName, std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > lowPriorityQueueName) Line 198   C++
TestDB.exe!SQSTest::SQSTest() Line 18   C++
TestDB.exe!testSQS() Line 24    C++
TestDB.exe!main(int argc, wchar_t * * argv) Line 183    C++
[External Code]
```

Answer (score 2):

After investigation, this is due to mismatched link types. Aws-cpp-sdk-core is linked in statically, while Aws-cpp-sdk-sqs was being linked dynamically. Changing the nuget packages to use the same link types, will fix the issue.

Comment: It compiles while the the other way does not. in any case, that should not cause this error deep in the dll.

Comment: could I see more context? There are lots of reasons the sample you posted will have problems, but I suspect that's not what you are actually doing.
For example, are you calling InitAPI multiple times in the same process. Is something else calling ShutdownAPI() etc...

Comment: Unfortunately this is the context. Stepped through is with the debugger. I pack all in a dll and call from a test program which is plain and simple. Only a single InitAPI call, no ShutdownAPI called yet. I run okay through the same sequence when I need an S3 client. I will be happy to try other ways, but it does crash very early with exactly those lines. Any specific idea on what can cause it that i can look for?

Comment: so assigning a pointer to a stack object instance, it it compiles will segfault. What line is throwing the segfault. I need you to narrow it down to the line of code causing the problem to he able to help.

Comment: I call this line and fail before returning:

Aws::SQS::SQSClient sqs = new Aws::SQS::SQSClient(Aws::Auth::AWSCredentials("abc", "def"), configuration);

Two things.
1. IMHO. if the return address is wrongly defined on the stack it will cause issues only after returning from the call where it might have corrupted the stack. Until then, there is not reason for it to fail, but it does not return.
2. Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000000 points to a null (non initialized?) pointer at 0x000007FEE4E9C83C (aws-cpp-sdk-core.dll), which is the AWS DLL.

Comment: @YishaiS. did you build from scratch or are you using NuGet? The reason I ask is that there may be a stack alignment problem it you don't have matching versions if you are using NuGet. Also, is there anyway you can get a stack trace for me? Or are these release builds?

Comment: @YishaiS.also, compiler optimizations may change execution order as well, so it wouldn't hurt to fix the type issue on your allocation before running the next time.

Comment: Jonathan, thanks for all your help!
Changed the call to use "Aws::SQS::SQSClient* sqs..". 
Updated all the NuGet packages to be of the same version (ends with .60).
Still same crash. Here is the stack:

Comment: Its to long for a comment.I;ll add it to the question

Comment: So the stack trace doesn't seem to have any real info. Is there any version of the full lib (all packages) with symbols in one dll I can download and try to use? Maybe it will provide soem what more info.

Comment: Get the symbols package from nuget and build in debug mode. You can then step through the source (assuming you have it downloaded) and see exactly where it is failing. At the least, try just building in debug and seeing if you get a better stack trace.

Comment: @YishaiS. are you the same user as this issue:? https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-cpp/issues/357

We should move the conversation to a single place. I recommend doing it here.

Comment: @YishaiS. but it looks like this may be a project configuration issue. I left correspondence on the github issue.